# c# how to mimic a button press from a different form

Tags: c#, winforms

i am creating a replica of my current form:

```
    Form form2 = new Form1();
    form2.Show();
```

i need to be able to run events on form2 like the button_click and fill out some text in a textbox. how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to edit the controls on a form is to create a method that exposes this feature (like an EditTextBox1(string) kind of method).
In general, when you want to manipulate a form from code (except for the form's code) and not the gui, it's wise to create a method for this (in the form class).

Regarding running events, it's unclear what you mean

Comment: fine then how would i run a click event?

Comment: If you are looking to run the method that's being invoked when the mouse is clicked, just make it public. Button1_click is just a method, nothing more. The reason it runs when you click the button is because it was signed to the click event of the button (Button1.Click += Button1_click;). If I understood you correctly, just make the method public and call it

Answer (score 1):

To run event handlers from another class make them `public`, default access modifier for class members in c# is `private`.  note that this will very rapidly lead to highly coupled spaghetti code ... you should really refactor so that you don't need to call event handlers between forms like this, it's a bad habit.

Comment: how do i make them public please?